# Is in a program with MVC a model and a view and a controller needed for every class that has some outputs?

Tags: model-view-controller, uml

I'm net to `UML` and the `MVC-Pattern` and I don't know how to exactly bring it into my program. I'm want to build a Slotmachine and I'm trying to bring a UML for that Slotmachine to life. I don't know if I need just 1 controller, 1 view and 1 model for the game or many of them for different classes. Following a short experiment in UML: [Screenshot of a UML](https://gyazo.com/136033edf08c4d9df4669d59fb17f8bf). Maybe somebody coul explain that to me.

Thank you!

Comment: Just a remark, UML could not answer to a question like "do I need one or more controller", this is a design choice. UML help to model how your controller(s) interact(s) with other classes but it can not help to decide how to design your system.

Comment: Okay, but i just want to know if it is wrong to have many Controllers and views and models in the same Output or not. Can i use them for every class that creates an Output in the gui? Or should i do every Output of the classes in just one view? Just dont get it...

Answer (score 0):

For building an MVC app, you first have to choose a specific MVC approach (because there are many, see this [book chapter about MVC](http://web-engineering.info/book/WebApp1/ch06.html)), and then you make a UML class diagram for designing your ***model*** classes. You normally don't use UML for designing the ***views*** and ***controllers*** of your app because they are based on your ***model*** classes.

Typically, for each model class, such as `Game`, you need one controller and four 'views' (or better *user interfaces*): one for each of the four CRUD data management use cases. I have written two tutorials that show how to use a simple MVC architecture approach:

1. [Building a Minimal JavaScript MVC App in Seven Steps](http://web-engineering.info/tech/JsFrontendApp/minimal-tutorial.html)
2. [Building a Minimal Java MVC App in Seven Steps](http://web-engineering.info/tech/JavaJpaJsfApp/minimal-tutorial.html)

Comment: Wow okay thank you very much for your answer, i will definetly read me through that! And thank you for that hint!

Comment: Don't forget to accept/upvote my answer if you find it useful.